# Lifetime of anonymous object run as thread in Java

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Within a method I have the following,

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                       ...
                       ...
                     }                       
                };              
                new Thread(r).start();
```

What is the lifetime of this anonymous object and thread ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the lifetime of this anonymous object and thread ?

1) Thread keeps running until you stop it.

2) Object scope(`r`) is with in the method.

Comment: If the object is destroyed when you leave the method, how can the thread still run after that, ie isn't the code that the thread was running, ie the anonymous object, now gone ? thx

Comment: The method stack thread returns after the method execution completes. Before  it is terminating it creates another thread. So it runs on it own. There is no need of that method stack thread to be live to run the created thread. Making sense ?

Comment: Just to be clear:  No object is ever destroyed just because "you leave the method."  An object _may_ be destroyed when there is no longer any chain of reference that can be traced from some thread's stack to the object in question.  In your case, there will be at least one reference to the new Thread object from its own stack, and a reference from the Thread object to your Runnable object, so as long as that stack exists (i.e., as long as the run() method has not exited), the Thread and the Runnable are safe from the garbage collector.

Comment: @jameslarge That'
s a clear and valuable comment  :)